# Tactical stance in COD MW3 - is there RL equivalent?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, first-person-shooter

The new tactical stance in COD MW3 - is it based on reality? I can't imagine why holding a weapon tilted would give you an advantage in combat. Any insight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a stance called C.A.R.(abbreviation for Center Axis Relock) system - which nowadays called 360° CQD(close-quarter defense) - that focuses on close range combat, that is used by US army, police, and John Wick ([Keanu even published his training](https://youtu.be/Xii9_oWQ7HY)).

There is ton of explanation website, but I believe [this website](https://gunsmagazine.com/discover/whats-the-c-a-r-system/) is best for understanding it. Here's a quote for the cants:

> 30 Degree Cant More Than Hollywood Cool:
>
> You might question the 30 degree cant. Trying to hold the pistol upright in this position is unnatural and strains the arm. The cant makes it more natural for the shooter, yet has little effect on accuracy at these short distances.
>
> At closer distances, weapon retention becomes a concern and the position changes to a “High” where the gun is brought back against the chest, pointing to the weak side. It is still gripped with both hands, allowing a more robust hold and the ability to use the body as an effective block against a bad guy’s gun grab. Shooting unsighted from this level seems counterintuitive, yet it is very stable and can provide reasonably accurate and consistent hits on target at contact distances.

Comment: Ha nice one. When I saw the pics on that website it totally makes sense ..

Answer (score 0):

Call of Duty is grounded in reality, but that does not mean everything needs to be realistic.

One possible Answer to your Question could be "because it looks cool and fresh".